# I get different results every time I run my which uses lead function in SQL Impala

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I have the following code:

```
select *, lead(session_end_type) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by user_id, session_id, log_time) as next_session_end_type
from table_name;
```

However, it seems like this results in different results every time I run it.

What makes this difference?

Thanks in advance!

(I've checked that the code outputs different results through the following code:

```
create table t1
select *, lead(session_end_type) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by user_id, session_id, log_time) as next_session_end_type
from table_name;

create table t2
select *, lead(session_end_type) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by user_id, session_id, log_time) as next_session_end_type
from table_name;

select count (*) from
(
    select * from t1
    union
    select * from t2
) as t;
```

The resulting row count is different from t1's row count and t2's row count; meaning that the result of t1 and t2 is different.)

Comment: Is the combination `user_id, session_id, log_time` unique in the table? Otherwise you may get slightly different orders and thus different lead values and thus different counts.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you! I assumed that they were unique, but turned out they weren't! Didn't think about the log error!

Comment: Btw, there's no need to `order by user_id, session_id`, those columns are already in `partition by`

Comment: @dnoeth Oh thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no need to repeat the `partition by` columns in the `order by`.  You can simplify this to:

```
lead(session_end_type) over (partition by user_id, session_id order by log_time) as next_session_end_type
```

Second, if `log_time` is not unique for a given `user_id`/`session_id`, then the results are *unstable*.  Remember, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so if there are ties in sort keys then there is no "natural" order to fall back on.

You can check this wtih:

```
select user_id, session_id, log_time, count(*)
from table_name
group by user_id, session_id, log_time
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you do have a column that uniquely identifies each row (or each user/user session row), then include that in the `order by`:

```
lead(session_end_type) over (partition by user_id, session_id
                             order by log_time, <make it stable column>) as next_session_end_type
                            )
```